# Defining a property of type 'class1 : interface1' into another interface

Tags: c#

I have some classes which implement an interface as follows:

```
class C1 : IpropTemplate { ... }

class C2 : IpropTemplate { ... }

:
```

Also there is some other class which implements another interface:

```
class C3 : IclassTemplate { ... }
```

Now, I need to specify the signature of a property into the `IclassTemplate` that forces the `C3` to have a property which is implemented from `IpropTemplate`. (such as `C1` or `C2`, etc.)

I tried this:

```
interface IclassTemplate
{
    ...
    IpropTemplate prop1 { get; set; }
}

class C3 : IclassTemplate
{
    ...
    public C1 prop1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

In this case, compiler produces an error indicating that `C3` does not implement interface member `IclassTemplate.prop1` and that the `C3.prop1` cannot implement `IpropTemplate.prop1` because it does not have the matching return type of `IpropTemplate`.

What should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make your C3 implementation *only* deal in C1 - after all, you've guarantee that this will be valid:

```
IClassTemplate c3 = new C3();
c3.Template = new C2();
```

If you only need to be able to *read* the property, it's slightly easier:

```
interface IClassTemplate
{
    IPropTemplate Template { get; }
}

public class C3 : IClassTemplate
{
    private readonly C1 c1 = new C1();

    IPropTemplate Template { get { return c1; } }
}
```

That lets the code in `C3` know that it's really a `C1`, but still implement the interface.

Another option is to make your interface generic:

```
interface IClassTemplate<T> where T : IPropTemplate
{
    T Template { get; set; }
}

public class C3 : IClassTemplate<C1>
{
    public C1 Template { get; set; }
}
```

Hopefully one of these will meet your need - if not, please give more details about what you're really trying to achieve - the bigger picture.

Comment: Thanks for your hint about putting a field at interface. I didn't put a field in my prog. but here I wrote the code snippet carelessly, I've corrected it.

Comment: @Mimi: Okay, I'll edit. You might want to make your sample names follow .NET naming conventions at the same time ;)

Answer (score 0):

The return type is part of the signature of the property - it has to be of type `IpropTemplate`:

```
public IpropTemplate prop1
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Then you can assign it to a C1 ans well as C2 objects.

```
...
prop1 = new C1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of C1 , write IPropTemplate in property signature. After infernaly you can operate on C1 type, but the signature has to expose an interface as IclassTemplate defined it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
class C3 : IclassTemplate 
{
    ...
    public C1 prop1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
   public IpropTemplate prop1 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: How does that even work? You can't have two distinct properties of the same name in the same class.